# text-decorations tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I did not have any idea what tag to apply to [Crossing out sentences](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13696/crossing-out-sentences). So I invented [text-decorations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-decorations), which would cover underlines, strike-outs, etc. Do you think this is a useful tag to keep, and if so, should we retroactively apply it to relevant questions?

---

Edit: It seems that the general idea is accepted, but the name of the tag could be improved. The following suggestions have been made

- [text-decorations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-decorations)
- [text-properties](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-properties)
- [character-formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-formatting)
- [text-effects](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-effects)
- separate tags: [underlining](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underlining), [strike-out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strike-out), etc.

Comment: It's a pity that we can't define parent-tags, i.e. that {underlining} would be a child of {text-decorations}.

Answer (score 3):

If we did want *one* generic term to cover all these sorts of things (underlining, strikeout, osv) then perhaps **-effects** is better than **-decorations**.  I feel that "effects" is a more common term (but then I could be wrong, and I'm probably the worst person to comment on tags as I've yet to figure out what to do with them).

Answer (score 1):

A few days ago, I was tempted to create a new [underlining](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underlining) tag for another question but didn't do it because the tag seemed so petty. However, a more general [text-decorations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-decorations) tag is a good idea. And yes, I would apply such a tag retroactively. (But then, I'm lockstep. `;-)`)

Comment: Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo!

Answer (score 1):

A quich [search for underline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=underline) and also for underlining shows some questions - in my opinion already enough to get a tag. Many have tags such as [formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting), [layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout), [latex-general](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex-general)--tagging could be more specific there.

I don't like a [text-decorations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-decorations) tag though. Does a new user with a question about underlining really find this tag? I don't have a problem with an expressive [underlining](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underlining) tag.

As known, retagging should be done sparingly and very discreetly if at all.

Comment: I looked in vain for a suitable tag for this question after I answered it.  But when I saw {text-decorations} my immediate thought was "Huh?". I would prefer {underlining}.

Comment: @Alan: {underlining} doesn't make much sense for a question about striking out text.

Comment: @Caramdir, I realised that and added another suggestion in my answer. Although strikeout is just underlining raised by .5ex :-)  (Can't edit the comment though.)

Comment: I like the idea about one general tag for underlining, strike-out etc. The specific tags like {underlining} could be made synonyms to make it easier for people.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that if a tag is to be useful it has to cover a large enough but not overly large range of questions.  {text-decorations} is *so* tikz :-)

Do we want this tag to include questions about e.g. changing font shapes/weights?

What about {text-properties} (or to use a term familiar to Word users {character-formatting} (which in Word is contrasted with {paragraph-formatting}))?

Comment: These tags seem a bit too general for me. For example, one could argue that the font is also a text property.

Comment: While I agree that they are general (which is part of the goal), I think the relevant criterion for whether they are too general is whether people would think that {text-properties} would include fonts questions or whether {fonts} would be the logical better choice.  This, of course, is an empirical question, although I don't know that we can do the required experiment.  I think what some of us don't like is that 'decorations' is not a term in common use (other than in tikz) so it might not come to mind as the right category.  That's part of the reason I suggested categories similar to Word's.

Comment: I didn't say that {text-decorations} is a good choice (it was just the only idea I had). What do you think about Andrew's {text-effects}?